# CarrierWave S3 File Retrieve Issue - undefined method `body'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

This is driving me nuts.  Im using CarrierWave with Amazon S3, I can safely upload a file to the bucket, and Im trying to now (in a different request) retrieve the file and deliver it as a download to the browser.

The files can be anything, .zip file etc. Im not using it for image storage.

The Bucket is private, not public so I can't just use the S3 URL.

Here's my retrieve code:

```
au = @note.attachment
au.retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(@note.attachment.to_s))
au.cache_stored_file!
```

The code errors on the cache_stored_file! line.  Throwing the error:

```
undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

I inspect the object and it looks fine to me, and if I output @note.attachment, I can clearly see the amazon s3 URL with keys etc.

Iv been all over the web and I can figure it out.  Iv found a handful of people with the same issue who solved it by doing things that are irrelevant to my case (like using some imagemagick method),  again, these are just files.

No handling or image work, I just want to return the files to the browser as a download.

Can anyone please help?

Here is my uploader:

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "#{Rails.env}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/attachments"
  end
end
```

and the trace

```
carrierwave (0.8.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:225:in `read'
carrierwave (0.8.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:77:in `sanitized_file'
carrierwave (0.8.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:116:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.8.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:73:in `cache_stored_file!'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think these lines don't make sense:

```
au = @note.attachment
au.retrieve_from_store!(File.basename(@note.attachment.to_s))
au.cache_stored_file!
```

`retrieve_from_store` is something you would typically call on the uploader, not on the attached object. The complicated step of passing the basename of the attachment to itself should make warning bells go off all over.

If I understand you correctly you simply want to give the user the possibility to download the file that you stored in S3.

You can do this is in a couple of ways.

The easiest is to call `@note.attachment.url` and print the url as a link that your user can click.

Another way is to redirect the user to the url in controller action.

```
# notes/1/download_attachment   
def download_attachment
  @note = Note.find(params[:id)
  redirect_to @note.attachment.url
end
```

One last way is to act as a proxy server/cache, and fetch the file from S3 and return it.

You could do it something like this in your controller:

```
file = open(@note.attachment.url)
send_data file
```

Please note that I didn't have the chance to test this last code snippet.

You can read more about [send_data here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/DataStreaming/send_data).

Comment: Thanks for your response, that's helpful!  but what about if these files are secure/private files?   Do I really want to expose the S3 URL?  These attachments could be financial documents,   so it was told to me that I needed to pull the files down to the local cache first and then serve them to the client.      Is that correct?

Comment: I actually have a similar situation in one of my projects. What I did is that I use https for all communication with the servers. I give the users the links, but I make them temporary links which expire very rapidly. That way, an attacker would have to both break the http encryption and do it very quickly, since the link will expire. Expiring links is easy to configure using Carrierwave/Fog.

Comment: But you could also cache the files, using some variation of the last method that I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: That sounds like it could work,  would you mind pointing me in the direction of where I could find info about short expiring links? I havnt come across it in my googling?

Comment: Never mind, I found it ... Now if I could just figure out how to get the server side encryption enabled.   Thanks for your help Jesper!