# Is it possible to download a file via CarrierWave, from a secure resource, and serve it to the browser through the Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, azure-blob-storage

I have an existing Rails 4 application in which I use Carrierwave to handle attaching Office docs. Carrierwave is backed by Azure blob storage. It's worked wonderfully for several months.

Recently, someone in IT created an account in the application, under a different name, and has discovered that you can download a file from the (public) blob container, though a plain web browser, as long as you know the exact 200-character-or-so path and filename combination. To me, this is no worse than files leaving the network via sneakernet, but, of course, this situation has been deemed an untenable security risk of vital company information.

I've been trying to figure out a way to get my attachment controller to download the file for me, and serve it to the browser, so that I can turn off the public access to the blob container. Carrierwave should understand how to download that file, securely, as it already has been configured with the location, host, and security key, but, for the life of me, I can't figure out how I might call some method in the library to do this.

The closest I've gotten is [this module](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/CarrierWave/Uploader/Download/RemoteFile), which seems promising, but I can't figure out how to invoke it in a useful way. It still wants to deal with the file through a public-type URL.

I've also tried creating a Tempfile, writing it, and send_file-ing it, but it only seems to serves an html file with an error message about not being able to access the temp file.

```
  def show
    suffix = /(?<=\.)[^.]*$/.match(@attachment.document.path)[0]
    f = Tempfile.new([@attachment.filename, suffix], encoding: 'ascii-8bit')
    f.write @attachment.document.read
    send_file f, :disposition => 'attachment'
    f.close
    f.unlink
  end
```

`@attachment.document.read` gives me the ASCII dump of the file, and I can't find a method that will read it as binary.

I just keep thinking that there's got to be some easy method in CarrierWave to tell it to "go get this file via the same way you stored it", but I can't find it.

Comment: Finally found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239876/carrierwave-s3-file-retrieve-issue-undefined-method-body, but there's no answer there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 problems with my code, above. First, in debugging, I noticed that there was a name collision with using `f` as the temp file variable name. (Something to do with Kernel.)

Second, the way the action is being rendered, the file isn't being sent at the moment the `send_file` method is called. It actually passes through some more Rails hoops before that. So I can't clean up the file right after that line, or the file doesn't exist to send to the client when Rails is finally done with the render. (I shouldn't have to clean up the file anyway, as Tempfile is designed to put files in places that get cleaned up by the system.)

So this works:

```
  def show
    suffix = /\.[^.]*$/.match(@attachment.document.path)[0]
    scratch_file = Tempfile.new([@attachment.filename, suffix], encoding: 'ascii-8bit')
    scratch_file.write @attachment.document.read
    send_file scratch_file, :disposition => 'attachment'
  end
```